# Showing points and total points using exercise or any other suitable package

Tags: exam, exercises, xsim, points

I want to prepare a book with many chapters (and sections), notes, exercises and linked solutions at the end of the book . I decided to adopt the example from on [matching enumerated exercises with their answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277312/matching-enumerated-exercises-with-their-answer-when-using-the-answers-package). However, I want to display points per question part as shown here [image: on the image]. The `exam` package

```
\documentclass{memoir}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{ntheorem}
 \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
 \theoremseparator{.}

 \usepackage{answers}
 \Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
 \renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{\small{#1.}}
 \newtheorem{ex}{}[section]
 \renewcommand{\theex}{\arabic{ex}}
 \newenvironment{Ex}[1]{\begin{trivlist}\item \textsc{#1} %
 \renewcommand{\Currentlabel}{#1}}{\end{trivlist}}

\usepackage{multicol}
 \newenvironment{mtmulticols}[1]{%
 \Writetofile{ans}{\string\begin{multicols}{#1}}
 \begin{multicols}{#1}}{\end{multicols}%
 \Writetofile{ans}{\string\end{multicols}}}

\Newassociation{solitem}{Solutionsubitem}{ans}
  \renewcommand{\Solutionsubitemlabel}[1]{#1}
  \newenvironment{Solutionsublist}{\Writetofile{ans}{\string\begin{Solution}  {\theex}}}{\Writetofile{ans}{\string\end{Solution}}}`

\begin{document}
 \chapter{Polynomials}
 \section{Partial fractions}
 \label{sec:partial-fractions}
 \tracingmacros=1
 \Opensolutionfile{ans}[partial-fractions]
 \section*{Exercises for Section \ref{sec:partial-fractions}}
 \vspace{-0.6cm}
 \hrulefill
 \begin{Ex}{Warm-ups}
 \end{Ex}
 \begin{ex}
 Who is the most famous mathematician of all time?
 \begin{sol}
 Euler
 \end{sol}
 \end{ex}
 \begin{ex}
 Resolve each of the following proper rational expressions (some filler here)  into partial fractions.
 \begin{multicols}{3}
 \begin{Solutionsublist}
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
 \item $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{(x - 1)(x - 2)}}$
  \begin{solitem}
    $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x - 2} - \frac{1}{x - 1}}$
  \end{solitem}
 \item $\displaystyle{\frac{5x + 4}{x^2 + x - 2}}$
  \begin{solitem}
    $\displaystyle{\frac{2}{x + 2} + \frac{3}{x - 1}}$
  \end{solitem}
 \item $\displaystyle{\frac{7x - 1}{2x^2 - x - 1}}$
  \begin{solitem}
    $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{2x + 1} + \frac{2}{x - 1}}$
  \end{solitem}
 \item $\displaystyle{\frac{25}{18x^3 - 9x^2 - 11x + 2}}$
  \begin{solitem}
    $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{3x + 2} - \frac{12}{6x - 1} + \frac{1}{x -
      1}}$
  \end{solitem}
 \item $\displaystyle{\frac{x^2 + 15x - 4}{(x + 1)(x + 2)(x - 8)}}$
  \begin{solitem}
    $\displaystyle{\frac{2}{x - 8} + \frac{2}{x + 1} - \frac{3}{x +
      2}}$
  \end{solitem}
 \item $\displaystyle{\frac{48}{(x^2 - 1)(x^2 - 9)}}$
  \begin{solitem}
    $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{x - 1} + \frac{3}{x + 1} - \frac{1}{x + 3}
    + \frac{1}{x - 3}}$
  \end{solitem}
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{Solutionsublist}
 \end{multicols}
 \end{ex}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}
  \section*{Answers for Section \ref{sec:partial-fractions}}
 \input{partial-fractions}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: At a certain point, it becomes easier to start from scratch than modify a package.  There are a number of ways to set this up, including tabular and \makebox.  You will need a counter for the (a) (b)... and another if you want to automatically compute the total.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the answer package but would propose a solution to add score points consisting of three parts:

1. Use of a displayed math environment with `\tag` to display the appropriate score (additional benefit: remove need for endless `\displaystyle` calls).
2. Redefine the `\tag` format to use brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()` (possible with the `mathtools` package).
3. Tweak from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58145) to get the displayed math to appear on the same line as the item number.

Further adjustment may be required to suit your tastes. For starters, I would personally suggest adding at least `leftmargin=*` in the enumerate environment options in order to give your equations a bit more space (you may also wish to experiment with the `fleqn` option of the amsmath package).

*Additional* code for your preamble:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Change tag form to brackets []
\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets}
% Tweak to have displayed math appear on same line as \item. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58145
\newcommand\Item[1][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax  \item \else \item[#1] \fi
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
```

Example use:

```
 \begin{ex}
 \begin{multicols}{2} % Changed from 3
 \begin{Solutionsublist}
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
 % Optional - give equations a bit more room with leftmargin=*
 %\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=(\alph*)] 
 \Item 
 \begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{(x - 1)(x - 2)}\tag{1}
 \end{equation}
 \begin{solitem}
    $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x - 2} - \frac{1}{x - 1}}$
 \end{solitem}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Solutionsublist}
\end{multicols}
\end{ex}
```

Note only 2 columns of equations sensibly fit (I've also left the solutions unchanged - you may want to change how you format these as well).

Example output:

[image]

This approach has the benefit that you can label each equation and retrieve the score at any time easily with `\eqref`.